# Powerpoint 2013 alternative to saving as .mht

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerpoint, web-parts, office-2013

My work laptop was just reimaged with office 2013 and one of the first things I noticed was the removal of the option to save a ppt as a single file web page. One of the products that I routinely update on our sharepoint is a ppt slide with hyperlinks and rollover screen tips to make it interactive when viewed as a presentation.

I'm looking for advice on finding an alternative to using a .mht in conjunction with a page viewer web part to display the "live" slide. I'll also note that the office web apps feature is not currently enabled or available in the site settings.

Thank you and take care.

Comment: Are you looking to find an alternative product or for advice on coding a solution yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think a coding solution is best unless the alternative product is in Office Suite 2013 since this is for military staff work so I'm pretty much stuck with what I have as far as programs.

Comment: If you're stuck with what's built into PPT 2013, then you're stuck period for HTML/MHT output.  It's no longer built into the app.  It's possible to write out images of each slide in HTML format and to preserve most hyperlinks (including ALT text) but it's quite a bit of work.